# Как убрать зум (когда можно пальцами увеличить контент) у мобильной Opera/Safari на iOS 10 и выше?

Tags: css, вёрстка, кроссбраузерность

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,
      maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Прописал этот мета тэг, контент нельзя приблизить во всех браузерах, кроме Safari и Opera, там контент можно пальцами приближать контент и двигать его.

Comment: И слава богу! А тот как наделают сайтов - не приблизить, не увеличить. Хоть лупу бери натуральную, оффлайновую.

Comment: да, к сожалению это ломает логику полноэкранных приложений например типа "игра"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начиная с iOS 10 нет штатного способа отключить изменение масштаба. [Возможность увеличения включена всегда.](https://webkit.org/blog/7367/new-interaction-behaviors-in-ios-10/) Так как Opera использует тот же движок, то и там тоже это нельзя.

До iOS 12 были способы [перехватывать события увеличения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38573198/93540), не давая изменить масштаб от исходного. Некоторые я попробовал - уже не работают.

Comment: Т.е понять и простить?)  Или есть вариант побороть эту причуду через js? Есть ли смысл?

Comment: Типа того. Попробуйте, но у меня не получилось никакими из примеров.